# How to get methods list in scala

Tags: scala

In language like python and ruby to ask the language what index-related methods its string class supports (which methods’ names contain the word “index”)  you can do

```
“”.methods.sort.grep /index/i
```

And in java

```
List results = new ArrayList();  
Method[] methods = String.class.getMethods();  
for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {  
    Method m = methods[i];  
    if (m.getName().toLowerCase().indexOf(“index”) != -1) {  
        results.add(m.getName());  
    }  
}  
String[] names = (String[]) results.toArray();  
Arrays.sort(names);  
return names;
```

How would you do the same thing in Scala?

Comment: Think i found it
"wow".getClass.getMethods.toList.map(m => m.getName).sort((a, b) => (a compareTo b) < 0 ).filter( s => s.matches("index(.*)"))

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you going to do with those method names once you've got them? If it's so you know what you can type next in an interactive setting, the Scala REPL has good tab-completion. Check it out.

Comment: Excellent tip, Randall! For some reason I just never thought to try...

Comment: The tab completion doesn't find methods from traits. For example, "`1.m<tab>`" suggests nothing, but "`1.max(2)`" works fine.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Curious that no one tried a more direct translation:

```
""
.getClass.getMethods.map(_.getName) // methods
.sorted                             // sort
.filter(_ matches "(?i).*index.*")  // grep /index/i
```

So, some random thoughts.

- The difference between "methods" and the hoops above is striking, but no one ever said reflection was Java's strength.
- I'm hiding something about `sorted` above: it actually takes an implicit parameter of type `Ordering`. If I wanted to sort the methods themselves instead of their names, I'd have to provide it.
- A `grep` is actually a combination of `filter` and `matches`. It's made a bit more complex because of Java's decision to match whole strings even when `^` and `$` are not specified. I think it would some sense to have a `grep` method on `Regex`, which took `Traversable` as parameters, but...

So, here's what we could do about it:

```
implicit def toMethods(obj: AnyRef) = new { 
  def methods = obj.getClass.getMethods.map(_.getName)
}

implicit def toGrep[T <% Traversable[String]](coll: T) = new {
  def grep(pattern: String) = coll filter (pattern.r.findFirstIn(_) != None)
  def grep(pattern: String, flags: String) = {
    val regex = ("(?"+flags+")"+pattern).r
    coll filter (regex.findFirstIn(_) != None)
  }
}
```

And now this is possible:

```
"".methods.sorted grep ("index", "i")
```

Comment: That's almost what the OP had except for the "sorted" Are yo using 2.8?

Comment: @Oscar Yes, that's 2.8. On Scala 2.7 there is `sort`, but not on all collections.

Comment: This isn't really the same -- in Ruby `x.methods` includes methods accessible via mixins, whereas `x.getClass.getMethods` does not in Scala. Try `1.methods` in Ruby and then try `1.getClass.getMethods` in Scala.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the scala REPL prompt. To find list the member methods of a string object, for instance, type "". and then press the TAB key (that's an empty string - or even a non-empty one, if you like, followed by a dot and then press TAB). The REPL will list for you all member methods.

This applies to other variable types as well.

Answer (score 5):

More or less the same way:

```
val names = classOf[String].getMethods.toSeq.
    filter(_.getName.toLowerCase().indexOf(“index”) != -1).
    map(_.getName).
    sort(((e1, e2) => (e1 compareTo e2) < 0))
```

But all on one line.

To make it more readable,

```
val names = for(val method <- classOf[String].getMethods.toSeq
    if(method.getName.toLowerCase().indexOf("index") != -1))
    yield { method.getName }
val sorted = names.sort(((e1, e2) => (e1 compareTo e2) < 0))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is as far as I got:

```
"".getClass.getMethods.map(_.getName).filter( _.indexOf("in")>=0)
```

It's strange Scala array doesn't have sort method.

**edit**

It would end up like.

```
"".getClass.getMethods.map(_.getName).toList.sort(_<_).filter(_.indexOf("index")>=0)
```

Comment: classOf[String].getMethods.toList.map(_.getName).sort( _ < _ ).filter( _.matches("index(.*)"))

This is what i got

Comment: It says: *warning: there were deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details* and gives me an empty list

Comment: `scala.Array` are implicitly converted to `scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray` which has the methods `sortBy` and `sortWith`. See the scaladocs: http://goo.gl/5pJD

Comment: No. I suppose the `sortBy` and `sortWith` methods are new in Scala 2.8.

Comment: In Scala 2.7.7, you had to do something like this to sort an array: http://pastebin.com/CnsAvU0C

Comment: Oh yeap, I tried that, but I discarded because.. .why?.. I don't remember, Oh yes, because it sorted the array it self instead of returning it and that would imply to create a reference prior to sorting, isn't?

Comment: Yes. Blame the library designers, not me. :P

Answer (score 3):

Now, wait a minute.

I concede Java is verbose compared to Ruby for instance.

But that piece of code shouldn't have been so verbose in first place.

Here's the equivalent :

```
    Collection<String> mds = new TreeSet<String>();
    for( Method m : "".getClass().getMethods()) {
        if( m.getName().matches(".*index.*")){  mds.add( m.getName() ); }
    }
```

Which has almost the same number of characters as the marked as correct, Scala version

Answer (score 1):

Just using the Java code direct will get you most of the way there, as Scala classes are still JVM ones. You could port the code to Scala pretty easily as well, though, for fun/practice/ease of use in REPL.