# Is there a way to get all the method name of a class in scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying to get all the method names of a class.

There was a similar question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886446/how-to-get-methods-list-in-scala)

With the given answer:

```
println("".getClass.getMethods.map(_.getName))
```

but it seems like it only gives the memory address of the method.

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@2acf57e3
```

Is there a way to get the name of the method instead?

Thanks

Comment: `println("".getClass.getMethods.map(_.getName).mkString(","))`

Answer (score 1):

Your get class method way is right, your print is wrong.

```
"".getClass.getMethods.map(_.getName)
```

this code response type is: `Array[String]()`

You are printing the Array adddres: `println(Array[String](...))`

The right way maybe:

```
 s.getClass.getMethods.map(_.getName) foreach println
```