# Is there a Scala equivalent to python's dir?

Tags: scala, debugging

Very simple question. I downloaded some scala code that I need to understand. I can run the program via sbt. I can debug the program with IntelliJ fine and set a breakpoint on the variable that I need. My question is:

Is there a way to know ALL of the methods that apply to a variable, class, function, etc? I know that scala is fully OOP by principle, so everything has methods, inheritance, etc. I just need to know which methods a particular object has.

In python I can dir(variable) to get an array of all the objects or methods around a certain variable. Is there a scala way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps this question: [How to get methods list in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886446/how-to-get-methods-list-in-scala)

Comment: Use the REPL completion answer in the link in the comment. That's aka `sbt console`. Programmatically, there's `scala.reflect`.