# How to print a Scala import

Tags: scala

I am working with an imported library, which I have no direct access to. I would like to convert the imported library class to a string and print it to investigate its functions further. How can I convert a class to String?

I already tried `.toString`, `print(libraryName)`

```scala
import Library._

object something {
    def something = {
        print(Library)
    }
}
```

The outcome is an object, e.g. `Library$@d126bba`. However, I would like to see the actual class in String format instead.

Comment: Is the library published in github? Or any other platform where you can search for the source code? Does the library provide any kind o **Java/Scala doc** where you can search for the API? You can also explore the object in an IDE or in the RELP _(as Brian suggested)_. What you asked is not really possible to do, since the library is already compiled to bytecode, it is not trivial to reconstruct the original **Scala / Java** code.

Comment: As I answered Brian, REPL is not available, hence, I need a way to reconstruct.

Comment: I would expect the online platform to provide correct documentation. If not, I am sorry but you are stuck. As I said, it is not a trivial task to reconstruct the original class, and **Scala** as a language does not provide an option to do that. - However, the closest you can get is to use **reflection** to print all methods and things like that, I really do not use to much of reflection, so I can't help you there, but there are plenty of documentation online and many stackoverflow questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886446/how-to-get-methods-list-in-scala).

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can get what you are looking for as a string. Another approach is to inspect it in the scala REPL.

Run `scala -cp library.jar` or whatever the jar name is.

Now, in the REPL run `import Library._`.

Typing `Library.` followed by tab should print out the classes and methods available.

For example I can explore the `java.date` package which consists of other packages.

```
scala> java.Date.
applet   awt   beans   io   lang   math   net   nio   rmi   security   sql ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this would actually work, however the code is on an online platform where REPL is not available.